# How do I view the contents of a .snap file?

Tags: snap

I need to see what is exactly packed inside of a `.snap` file, like we can inspect `.apk` files, for debugging purposes. Is there any way to extract it to files and folders or any `.snap` inspector similar to the `.apk` one on Android Studio?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can mount a snap-file as `squashfs`-filesystem:

```
sudo mount -t squashfs -o ro /path/to/my.snap /path/to/mountpoint
```

You can use the file-manager to browse to `/path/to/mountpoint` and view the contents of the snap-file.

Answer (score 1):

> Snaps are gpg signed squashfs files, you can use unsquashfs from the squashfs-tools package to unpack them

Source: https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/archive-manager-can-open-snap-files-what-kind-of-archives-are-they/1358