# How can I review the contents of a snap package?

Tags: apt, package-management, snap

I've been using Ubuntu MATE since 2017 on fringe ARM64 SBC boards. It takes me considerable time to iron out all the incompatibilities with drivers especially graphics drivers. It took me a long time to find the right combination of kernel drivers and MESA libraries that were reliable.

However all my efforts in setting up the underlying OS are in vain when it comes to snaps. Since the update to 22.04, I have been having the firefox & chromimum snaps consistently and often hanging my system. There is some talk that this appears to be MESA to GPU driver incompatibilities.

What I would like to do is look inside the snap package and determine what version of the MESA (and other) libraries it is using. I'm  thinking of something like this, but it doesn't give me the information I need:

```
snap firefox apt list --installed
```

I assume that my problems with the snaps can't be fixed, which is why I want to see the contents.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I view the contents of a .snap file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1162798/how-do-i-view-the-contents-of-a-snap-file) But this won't help you, because you can't make changes to a snap package. Snaps use a read only file system. That makes this question an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). It's always best to ask about and provide details about your actual problem. This will increase your chances of obtaining a useful answer.

Comment: Not really.  That lets me see the files inside. To use that approach I would need to be able to recognise the versions of libraries based upon  already knowing where and what 
 specific files a package has.  Once mounted where would I go to find the specific MESA file or library that identified it's version.  I just looked at the contents of my mesa with dpgk-query -L mesa-common-dev and none of the files had an obvious version number in the name or had files with multi versions.